# Swift POST Request Method Not Allowed

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, urlsession

I Use Laravel as backend and I have below route to verify the users

```
$router->post('SignIn','Api\V1\UserProfileController@SignIn');
```

I have tested this route many time using postman and its working fine, now i want to send post request from my app using below request

```
let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.xxx.xxx/BARI/public/Api/V1/Verify")!
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let param  : [String : Any] = ["ph_number" : userDefaults.string(forKey: "ph_number")!, "code" : smsNumberTF.text!]
            request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: param, options: [])
           let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
           configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(30)
           configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TimeInterval(30)
           let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
                if(error != nil){
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        self.progress.stopAnimating()
                        self.isLoading = false
                        // show connection error alert
                                           
                        print("connection error : \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                   
                    
                }else{
                    let outputStr  = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) as String?
                     print(outputStr)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                                
                       do {
                                                     
                        self.progress.stopAnimating()
                        self.isLoading = false
                            let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(BasicResponse.self, from: data!)
                                                                  
                            if(jsonData.statusCode == 1000){
//                            let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
//                            userDefaults.set("+964" + self.phoneET.text!, forKey: "contact_number")
//                            let vc = Verfiy()
//                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
                            }else{
                             //self.alert.show(target: self.view, message: jsonData.message!)
                            }
                                                                  

                            }
                             catch let jsonerr {
                             print("error serrializing error",jsonerr)
                                                                       
                             }
                                                                
                         }
                    
                }
            }
            task.resume()
```

But Im getting `Method Not Allowed` response back? what Im missing her!?

Any Help will be much appreciated

Comment: What is BasicResponse and what does "jsonData.statusCode == 1000" mean?

Comment: You need to actually use the request you make. `let task = session.dataTask(with: url)` should be `let task = session.dataTask(with: request)`.

Comment: @ElTomato this a Codable struct represent the backend response

Comment: @Crowman Thanks man, its solved the issue